# Confused about data flow and parts involved in sending iOS push notifications through a database

Tags: objective-c, ruby-on-rails, database, heroku, push-notification

I'm creating a college dining menu app, in which I need to send push notifications based on the daily menus.

I only know objective-c, so I'm inexperienced with concepts such as databases that are needed for this task.

What I understand:

- I need to parse the data from the online dining menu and store it in
  some database
- I check daily if the current menu has what I'm looking for, and alert the Apple Push Notification service if it does
- Above two points must be done without independently of my app, since the app won't be open at all times.

Resources I found:

- Heroku -- a cloud platform where I can store the data
- [Helios](http://helios.io/) -- "provides backend services" like push notifications and can be implemented w/ Heroku (not entirely sure what it does)
- Ruby on Rails

What I'm confused about:

- How do I store the data in the database? Do I have to write a program
  with ruby on rails that scrapes the web data and then somehow add
  this to Heroku?
- What exactly does Helios help me with?
- What is my actual objective-c app code responsible for doing?
- Are there any other parts/better resources I left out?

Any pointers would help. Also, I'm trying to avoid using any paid services for server/database tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain it for you:

> - [Heroku](http://heroku.com) is just a way to host on the Amazon AWS cloud infrastructure. It doesn't store your DB - it provides access to db
>     infrastructure, but doesn't host the DB itself
> - If you want to store cross-platform data in your iOS application, you need to connect to a third-party db (this is how FB works)
> - This means if you want to keep up with menu updates on your phone, you'll need to firstly have a central db (hosted on Heroku's
>     recommended db infrastructure), and then use the iOS app to connect to
>     it

The trick will be to take any updates from the database & display them using a push notification. I don't know about this, but the Rails part I *can* tell you about:

1. If you want to store a menu in a db, you'll need a db. You can get one either at AWS or Heroku *(notice how the `db` != `rails`)*
2. Next, you need data in that db. This is where rails comes in - you'll be best using an infrastructure such as Rails or CakePHP to  manage the data
3. If you create a simple Rails app with admin backend, you'll be able to upload as much data as required to your db. If you need to "scrape" the data, you can create a simple script & cronjob to get it & put into the db
4. Finally, each time the db updates, you need to send the update to your iOS app. I don't have much experience with this, but it seems you need to use the [pub/sub programming pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) to send the updates to your device (displaying them on screen as a result)

---

**Answers**

To answer your questions directly:

> 1. You store data in a db through Rails or another framework
> 2. Helios looks like it will connect your iOS app to your backend db infrastructure. Don't know how it works, but it looks pretty good
> 3. Your objective-C code gets the iOS app running natively on iPhone / iPad
> 4. I think you'll be okay with what you have here

Comment: thank you, could you clarify for me what you mean by making a rails app with admin backend?

Comment: Sure - a Rails app can be anything you want. So in order to create the app you want, you really need to be able to manage the data in the db. This is normally done by using an "admin" area in Rails - gems like [ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/) or [rolling your own](http://iain.nl/backends-in-rails-3-1)

Comment: I skimmed over the ActiveAdmin link: If it's backend code I need, where does the interface come into play?

Comment: Interface as in Helios or the front-end of the app?

Comment: The ActiveAdmin link said its purpose is "generating administration style interfaces."  I was just confused how that is relevant to what I needed

Comment: Oh okay. The reason I mentioned it was because if you want to keep a central data repository (with the likes of Rails), how are you going to manage the data? I was suggesting using an admin area like this to keep your data up to date, allowing you to then ping iOS with updates about it

Comment: Ideally, I wanted the program to automatically parse the page once a day and check on its own whether it needs to send notifications.

Comment: You can do that with Rails, just don't have a backend admin area!